# sql parameterized query in C# with string

Tags: c#, sql, database

```
com = new SqlCommand("SELECT pro_name from products where pro_name= @idP", con);
                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@idP",
                    Value = proNames[i]
                };
                com.Parameters.Add(param);
```

it works fine with integer type but for string its not working
it give error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query '(@idP nvarchar(4000))SELECT pro_name from products where pro_nam' expects the parameter '@idP', which was not supplied.'
```

Comment: Add also the setting for the SqlDbType in the constructor of the parameter with value equal to SqlDbType.NVarChar

Comment: I did same thing but still end with same error
com.Parameters.Add("@idP", SqlDbType.NVarChar,8000).Value=proNames[i];

Comment: Well, you are definitively adding that parameter, but if you get that error message then we should look at the remainder of your code when you execute that command to be certain that you haven't skipped something

Comment: what is the value of proNames[i]?

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance and make sure all necessary code and data present in the sample. I.e. in this case `proNames[i]` must be replaced with actual value (possibly simplified/sanitized) and actual call to DB shown (as frequently such problems come from constructing one query but using some other one to make actual call)

Comment: what is `i`? Is that code running in a loop?

Comment: yes it is loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try with passing proper `DBType`. In your case , this will be `NVarChar`

Make sure `proNames[i]` has value , Not `Null` or `EmptyString`

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "@idP",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, // your DBType
    Value = proNames[i]
};
```

You can also try adding parameter as below:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idP", proNames[i]);
```

Comment: ` proNames[i]` has value ?

Comment: worked with `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idP", "proNames[i]");` ?

Comment: it gives empty result

Comment: Not sure what are you missing now , please look at excepted answer at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316767/c-sharp-execute-sqlcommand-with-parameters-in-using-code-block

Comment: that accepted answer is worked with integer i want to do with string ......

Comment: did you tried executing SP directly on SQL server ?

Comment: same error on SQL as well ? as you have in application ?

Answer (score 1):

You should set SqlDbType and Size if it's VAR* type.

```
 SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter()
 {
     ParameterName = "@idP",
     SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
     Size = 4000,
     Value = proNames[i]
 };
```

By the way, if you'll want to pass NULL - you'll have to use `DbNull.Value` instead of just normal C# NULL.

Comment: What about `SqlDbType.NVarChar`?

Comment: Is it still saying parameter not supplied?